# Calculate the intersection points between linear function $f(x)$ and circle $C$ given $f(x)$ intersects C's center

Tags: geometry

Given a circle $C$ with center $A$ and radius $r$, and a linear function $f(x)$ which intersects with $A$, how do I calculate $P_1$ and $P_2$, the intersection points between $f(x)$ and $C$, strictly algebraically?

Every time I attempt to solve this, I run into the problem of how I know neither the $x$ nor the $y$ values of either intersection point.  In order to solve for $y$, I inevitably need to know $x$, and vice versa.

Here is the context of my problem: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/iaxsk4wovz.  Notice $A_{tx}$, $B_{tx}$, $A_{bx}$, and $B_{bx}$ are defined as scalars.  These are temporary placeholder constants in lieu of the equation I am attempting to construct.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have two equations in two unknowns (one quadratic equation, one linear). That should be enough information. If you [edit] the question to show us your work we may be able to help. Use mathjax https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a circle $(x-A_x)^2+(y-A_y)^2=r^2$ whose centre intersects a line $y=mx+c$ thus $A_y=mA_x+c\implies c=A_y-mA_x$.

This gives us two equations $(x-A_x)^2+(y-A_y)^2=r^2$ and $y=mx+A_y-mA_x$. Substituting $y$ we find $(x-A_x)^2+(mx+A_y-mA_x-A_y)^2=r^2=(x-A_x)^2+(mx-mA_x)^2$

$(1+m^2)(x-A_x)^2=r^2\implies x=A_x\pm r\sqrt\frac{1}{1+m^2}$

Which gives $y=A_y\pm mr\sqrt\frac{1}{1+m^2}$.

Thus $P_1=\left(A_{x}+r\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+m^{2}}},A_{y}+mr\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+m^{2}}}\right)$ while $P_2=\left(A_{x}-r\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+m^{2}}},A_{y}-mr\sqrt{\frac{1}{1+m^{2}}}\right)$.

Comment: This [worked perfectly](https://imgur.com/a/mWTNQuI)!  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Your linear equation through the point $(x_0,y_0)$
$(y-y_0) = m(x-x_0)$

A circle centered at $(x_0,y_0)$
$(x-x_0)^2 + (y-y_0)^2 = r^2$

Substitute from one into the other.

There will be two solutions that depend on $x_0, y_0, r,$ and $ m$

Comment: While this suggestion is great, the other goes into some more detail, so I am marking them as correct.  That said, I still appreciate your help!